# Getting localized file from app bundle?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, localization

I have localized sound files that i want to load according to the user languish.

I did it before but forgot how, I think it was simply

```
  NSLocalizedString(path,@"");
```

but it does not work now ?

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:extension]`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType: